# Azure VM key fingerprint

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, azure, azure-networking

I just created an Ubuntu VM on Azure. It says to use ssh to connect to the VM. When I try to SSH for the first time from the command line, it asks to verify ECDSA key fingerprint, but I cannot see it anywhere in the Azure Portal, whether it is the correct one of the machine I created.

Any help to find in Azure Portal would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it asks to verify ECDSA key fingerprint, but I cannot see it anywhere
>   in the Azure Portal,

It is a by design behavior, just enter your password to login.

like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'HOST NUMBER DELETED)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 'blah blah blah blah blah blah blah'.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'myiphost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@myiphost's password: your_password
```

---

**Update**:

Here is my test:

```
VM1: jasoncli
VM2: jasonubuntu
```

I am try to use VM1 to SSH VM2, after SSH completed, Linux will record the target server's(VM2) host key to VM1 `known_hosts`, like this:

```
[root@jasoncli@jasonye ssh]# cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
10.168.172.115 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBPeJQ8c7h002Flqu18aVYpUf+6HmXUS5UbMV7usyrrOUPyAMZcYBuek/DhEG2HmNAH0qLGurHdV66QCxM8oee1k=
```

We can find VM2's host key here:

```
root@jasonubuntu:/etc/ssh# cat ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub 
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBPeJQ8c7h002Flqu18aVYpUf+6HmXUS5UbMV7usyrrOUPyAMZcYBuek/DhEG2HmNAH0qLGurHdV66QCxM8oee1k= root@jasonubuntu
root@jasonubuntu:/etc/ssh# pwd
/etc/ssh
```

In this way, Linux will check the key to make sure the server is actually that server you are want to connect.

---

**Update3:**

For now, Azure does not support use console to connect to Azure VM. To get the `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`, we can use custom script extension via Azure portal, like this:

[image]

Here is the `script.sh`:

```
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

We can find the result in Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but if someone intercepted my initial `ssh` connection, I will be connecting to attacker's server won't I?

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of the key fingerprint?

Comment: you are right, ECDSA use for login without password, to achieve this we should have the permission to write the key to this vm, then we can login this VM without password.

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean by this. I have added my public ssh key (`id_rsa.pub` from my laptop) to `authorized_keys` on the server I am trying to ssh onto. So from perspective of the client, I can authenticate myself with my private key, but how do I know whether the server I am trying to connect to is actually that server? So I think that's where fingerprints come into play. And the idea is to check whether fingerprint displayed matches the actual one located in `/etc/ssh/`

Comment: Do you want to check known_host file?  SSH will record every ~/.ssh/known_hosts public key you’ve visited on your server, nest time when you visit to the same server, OpenSSH will check the public key. If the public key is different, OpenSSH will issue a warning to prevent you from being attacked by dns, hijack and so on

Comment: @eddyP23 I have update my answer, please check it, hope that helps:)

Comment: Yes, that is what I also have in mind. But the question asks how to ssh to the Azure VM the first time to see the fingerprints? E.g. when in OpenStack, you have an option to get to the console directly in the Web UI. That way, when I ssh using console on my laptop, I can verify the fingerprints

Comment: @eddyP23 For now, Azure does not support use console to get that information, but we can use custom script extension to get that key, I had update my answer, please check it:)

Comment: This feels completely unsatisfactory, but thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to run `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` to output the signature:

[image]

Comment: See also here my answer for hdinsights - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666865/how-to-retrieve-ssh-fingerprint-on-hdinsight-cluster/53666866#53666866